# Application Insights REST API - SSLException: Certificate for <api.applicationinsights.io>

Tags: rest, api, ssl, groovy

I'm using Application Insights REST API 
I write script in Groovy for reading custom events.

Everything work ok, but today my script get error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for  doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.api.loganalytics.io, api.loganalytics.io]

Do you have any opportunities to resolve this problem ?

Comment: what exact url/endpoint are you hitting?

Comment: https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/

more documentation about api:
https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Overview/URL-formats

Comment: that isn't a full endpoint, that's just a path (if you click that first /beta/apps link you'll even get an error saying so).  are you using /events /metrics, /query, etc?  the full url of what you're trying to use would be most helpful

Comment: I'm using /events/ so the full url is:  
https://api.applicationinsights.io/beta/apps/APP_ID/events. For now i resolve the problem adding .sslConfig(new SSLConfig().allowAllHostnames()) in my RestAssured response configuration.